# Java method visibility to specific packages

Tags: java, methods, package

Is it possible or not I am not sure? I want to create a java class which consisted of some methods, allowing some methods visibility to some specific packages by property file, annotations or any other else or some mechanism. Suppose -

```
package com.a;

public class A {
    public a();
    public b();
    public c();
}

package com.a;

public class A1 {
   public A1() {
      A a = new A();
      a.a();     // Visible when coding
      a.b();     // Not visible when coding
      a.c();     // Not visible when coding
   }
}

package com.b;

public class B {
   public B() {
      A a = new A();
      a.a();     // Not visible when coding
      a.b();     // visible when coding
      a.c();     // Not visible when coding
   }
}

package com.c;

public class C {
   public C() {
      A a = new A();
      a.a();     // Not visible when coding
      a.b();     // Not visible when coding
      a.c();     // visible when coding
   }
}
```

I am telling this because I look some package scenario that some methods from java class in library are not accessible from out side, but the methods are present in java. If we extract the java class then we can access the method, such as android tethering class in lower version.

Anybody can suggest or about this knowledge...

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achive that with help of [`AspectJ`](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/) or [Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/aop.html). Try to write `@around` pointcut which will throw some exception, if your methods will be called from  context, which is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think there is anything for such case in core java. You can look at `AspectJ` as given by Alex. A sample program can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-aop-aspectj-annotation-example/).